# Proving a formula for the product of two measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu), g \in \mathcal{L}^1(\nu)$ (meaning that $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable with respect to the measure $\mu$, and analogous for $g$).

I want to show that the function $h(x, y) = f(x) g(y)$ is an element of $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu \otimes \nu)$ (that is, $h$ is integrable with respect to the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$), and that $h$ satisfies the formula:

$$\int_{X \times Y} h d(\mu \otimes \nu) = \int_X f d \mu \cdot \int_Y g d \nu$$

I'm having trouble getting started with this excercice. To show that $h$ is integrable, it's sufficient to show that $h$ is measurable in $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ (the product-$\sigma$-Algebra), with respect to the product measure $\mu \otimes \nu$? Would it therefore be sufficient to consider any set $A \cdot B = \{a \cdot b | a \in A, b \in B\}$, with $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ measurable, and show that $h^{-1}(A \cdot B)$ is measurable? Or would I need to show more than that, in order to show that $h \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu \otimes \nu)$?

I don't really know how to approach the formula though. I'm still a bit confused about how the product measure works with two totally different measures.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

In the context of abstract measure theory, those formulas are always proved in the same way:

1. prove the formula in the special case in which $f$ and $g$ are indicator functions of two sets (i.e. they vanish outside a given set and are equal to $1$ inside);
2. extend the result to simple functions, that are (finite) linear combinations of indicator functions;
3. conclude by some density-like argument.